# Best way to convert string array to ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, apache-axis

Please give me a efficient way to convert below String to Arraylist, (its get as a response from axis2 webservice)

```
[[
[1],  
[<2254, 89014103211118510720, C, D>],  
[<100, Colombo 01  , Western, 6.9378, 79.8436, Colombo 01  , Colombo>,  <11680, Kirillawala, Western, 0, 0, Kirillawala, Colombo>,  <11684, Wattala, Western, 0, 0, Wattala, Colombo>,  <11686, Kadawatha, Western, 0, 0, Kadawatha, Colombo>,  <11687, Kelaniya, Western, 0, 0, Kelaniya, Colombo>,  <11688, Heiyanthuduwa, Western, 0.7, 0.77, Heiyanthuduwa, Colombo>,  <11690, Rajagiriya, Western, 0, 0, Rajagiriya, Colombo>,  <20034, Yatihalagala, Central, 7.2916415, 80.5988306, Yatihalagala, KANDY>,  <20730, Rikillagaskada, Central, 7.15, 80.7833333, Rikillagaskada, KANDY>,  <20900, Teldeniya, Central, 7.3, 80.7666667, Teldeniya, KANDY>,  <33333, Kesbawa, Western, 0, 0, Kesbawa, Colombo>,  <44444, Hanwalla, Western, 0, 0, Hanwalla, Colombo>],  
[<VIZA_PP, VIZA_IDD PREPAID CARD, A, 99977>,  <VOUCHER, GIFT VOUCHER, A, 99970>,  <BRDB_PP, Broadband Pre Paid Card, A, 99995>,  <CDMA_PP, CDMA Pre Paid Card, A, 99996>,  <BELLKD, Bellkard, A, 99999>], 
[<10002#jei#col#0#null#null#0#null#0775555335#1#Colombo 04 >,  <10003#test#grdaj#1#6.9098358#79.8513162#2254#2013-10-29#7700555633#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10024#uuu#tu#0#null#null#0#null#9999999999#1#Colombo 08 >,  <10027#gg#jhh#0#null#null#0#null#0712654789#1#Colombo 08 >,  <10028#test1#colpitiya#0#null#null#0#null#0712345678#1#Colombo 08 >,  <10029#amal#add1#0#null#null#0#null#0712456186#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10030#dinesh chandimal#aaa#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-05-06#9999999999#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10031#Randika Perera#rrr#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-06-03#7756574766#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10032#Indika Herath#ttt#0#null#null#0#null#6834567892#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10033#jghg#ghjghj#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-05-06#8797797898#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10037#senarath#hgjghjghjg#0#null#null#0#null#4544544544#1#Colombo 01>,  <10039#nimantha#rtyutr#0#null#null#0#null#8798789887#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10040#yyy#hgfhf#0#null#null#0#null#9889898889#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10041#GAMINI DISSANAYAKE#Colombo#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#0733345699#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10042#roshan udaya#colombo01#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#0772123456#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10043#Sanjaya#Kadawatha#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-05-30#0773333480#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10044#aaa#bbb#1#6.9053231#79.8513079#2254#2013-08-27#7777777777#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10045#ggg#yyy#1#6.90808663#79.85050531#2254#2013-08-23#9999999999#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10046#suresh#borella#0#null#null#0#null#0712345678#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10047#buddika#kohuwala#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-06-03#7777777777#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10048#Udeshika#Rajagiriya#0#null#null#0#null#7777777777#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10049#SuperLink#Galle Road, Bamba#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-06-27#0112543764#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10235#qqq#qqq#1#6.90809226#79.85048474#2254#2013-08-23#8714444444#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10236#wwww#wwwww#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#8774444444#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10237#rrr#rrr#0#null#null#0#null#2255558888#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10238#aaa#aaa#0#null#null#0#null#0717177777#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10239#bbb#bbb#0#null#null#0#null#0777777777#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10240#ccc#ccc#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#0778888888#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10241#ddd#ddd#1#6.9040059#79.85238#2254#2013-08-27#0088855555#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10242#eee#eee#1#6.9040059#79.85238#2254#2013-08-27#9966655577#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10243#Niraj#Nittabuwa#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#7777712133#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10244#Dilum#Kohuwala#0#null#null#0#null#1111111111#1#Kadawatha>,  <10246#Namala#Namal Uyana#0#null#null#0#null#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10248#abc#abc123#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10249#cde#cde123#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10250#efg#efg123#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10251#A#A1#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10252#B#B1#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10253#C#C1#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10254#D#D1#0#null#null#0#null#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10255#E#E1#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10256#F#F1#0#null#null#0#null#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10257#G#G1#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-09-24#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10258#LankaBell#344 Galle Road#0#null#null#0#null#0777864914#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10259#Shamaal#23#0#null#null#0#null#0998766554#1#Kirillawala>,  <10260#Namala#123#0#null#null#0#null#0777655443#1#Kelaniya>,  <10261#Keshini#324#0#null#null#0#null#0999873564#1#Kelaniya>,  <10262#Ruwani#3334#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-10-14#0776554433#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10263#Shamaal #564134877#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-10-14#0774563555#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10264#Amila#6432#0#null#null#0#null#0777436437#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10265#Pathum#47#0#null#null#0#null#0000000000#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10266#A#100,  Kandy Rd, #1#0.0#0.0#2254#2013-10-17#0884754867#1#Kadawatha>,  <10267#Hasitha#352/1 old rd#1#0.0#0.0#2254#2013-10-15#0775456323#1#Kelaniya>,  <10270#Harshi#dsfdsfgds#0#null#null#0#null#0586756476#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10271#yyyyyyyyyyy#yyyyyyyyyyy#0#null#null#0#null#0000000000#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10272#ererererer#ererererererererer#0#null#null#0#null#6666666666#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10273#SSSSSSS#3535#0#null#null#0#null#0574856475#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10275#Chathurika Peris#87, ggttggfhrtr, gfhregygtgiihf#0#null#null#0#null#0775643334#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10276#Harith#gdjhgfdhgdsvgd#0#null#null#0#null#0777543234#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10277#A#A#0#null#null#0#null#1111111111#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10278#TironD#Kurunegala#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-10-16#9245923482#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10279#Hasitha#3#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-10-16#0775445675#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10280#Priyanka#Colombo#1#6.9378#79.84359833333333#2254#2013-10-21#0226567356#1#Colombo 01  >,  <10281#Test#Galle rd#0#null#null#0#null#0000000000#1#Colombo 01  >],  
[<1, BELLKD>,  <50, BELLKD>,  <100, BELLKD>,  <300, BELLKD>,  <500, BELLKD>,  <1000, BELLKD>,  <2500, BELLKD>,  <5000, BELLKD>,  <50, CDMA_PP>,  <100, CDMA_PP>,  <200, CDMA_PP>,  <300, CDMA_PP>,  <500, CDMA_PP>,  <1000, CDMA_PP>,  <2500, CDMA_PP>,  <5000, CDMA_PP>,  <250, N2PHONE>,  <500, N2PHONE>,  <1000, N2PHONE>,  <250, N2P_IND>,  <500, N2P_IND>,  <1000, N2P_IND>,  <250, N2P_MID>,  <500, N2P_MID>,  <1000, N2P_MID>,  <250, N2P_WST>,  <500, N2P_WST>,  <1000, N2P_WST>,  <1, TRITELL>,  <50, TRITELL>,  <100, TRITELL>,  <300, TRITELL>,  <500, TRITELL>,  <1000, TRITELL>,  <2500, TRITELL>,  <5000, TRITELL>,  <150, VIZA_PP>,  <350, VIZA_PP>,  <500, VIZA_PP>,  <1000, VIZA_PP>,  <2500, VIZA_PP>],  
[<10041#CDMA_PP#200#6#1#30-10-2013 15:34:24>,  <10042#CDMA_PP#200#7#1#30-10-2013 15:21:19>,  <10031#CDMA_PP#100#3#1#30-10-2013 15:20:15>,  <10047#CDMA_PP#100#2#1#30-10-2013 15:07:22>,  <10043#CDMA_PP#100#2#1#30-10-2013 15:05:24>,  <10041#CDMA_PP#100#1#1#30-10-2013 14:51:25>,  <10049#CDMA_PP#100#3#1#30-10-2013 14:45:26>,  <10267#CDMA_PP#100#1#1#30-10-2013 14:44:25>,  <10255#CDMA_PP#200#53#1#30-09-2013 15:46:43>,  <10243#CDMA_PP#200#43#1#24-09-2013 16:58:02>,  <10257#CDMA_PP#200#44#1#24-09-2013 16:58:02>,  <10254#CDMA_PP#200#47#1#24-09-2013 16:58:01>,  <10248#CDMA_PP#200#90#1#24-09-2013 16:58:00>,  <10043#CDMA_PP#200#1#1#24-09-2013 16:45:41>,  <10235#CDMA_PP#200#1#1#24-09-2013 16:28:50>,  <10044#CDMA_PP#200#1#1#24-09-2013 16:26:57>,  <10240#CDMA_PP#200#1#1#24-09-2013 16:25:53>,  <10241#CDMA_PP#200#1#1#24-09-2013 16:23:49>,  <10242#CDMA_PP#200#1#1#24-09-2013 16:21:49>,  <10249#CDMA_PP#200#1#1#24-09-2013 16:16:57>,  <10250#CDMA_PP#200#1#1#24-09-2013 16:15:53>,  <10251#CDMA_PP#200#1#1#24-09-2013 15:33:35>,  <10252#CDMA_PP#200#2#1#24-09-2013 15:32:31>,  <10253#CDMA_PP#200#2#1#24-09-2013 15:25:37>,  <10030#CDMA_PP#300#1#1#21-10-2013 17:23:41>,  <10266#CDMA_PP#300#3#1#17-10-2013 11:06:53>,  <10030#CDMA_PP#100#11#3#17-10-2013 11:04:52>,  <10003#CDMA_PP#100#2#1#16-10-2013 15:05:47>,  <10049#CDMA_PP#200#3#1#15-10-2013 17:07:11>,  <10045#CDMA_PP#200#1#1#15-10-2013 16:51:28>,  <10042#CDMA_PP#100#9#1#15-10-2013 12:00:05>,  <10003#CDMA_PP#300#6#1#14-10-2013 16:47:35>,  <10262#CDMA_PP#300#5#3#14-10-2013 10:24:16>,  <10030#CDMA_PP#50#4#1#11-11-2013 13:18:54>,  <10031#CDMA_PP#200#58#1#11-11-2013 11:19:36>,  <10030#CDMA_PP#200#120#1#11-11-2013 11:13:09>,  <10255#CDMA_PP#100#1#1#10-10-2013 10:33:08>,  <10033#CDMA_PP#200#10#1#08-11-2013 17:58:16>,  <10003#CDMA_PP#200#69#1#05-11-2013 12:19:52>],  
[22630],  
[],  
[<12050021, 6057160, 6057164, CDMA_PP, 50, 28-02-2014 12:17:08, 5.5, 0>,  <12050020, 6057140, 6057144, CDMA_PP, 50, 28-02-2014 12:17:08, 5.5, 0>,  <12050021, 6057150, 6057154, CDMA_PP, 50, 28-02-2014 12:17:08, 5.5, 0>,  <12100005, 6003841, 6003850, CDMA_PP, 200, 28-02-2014 12:17:08, 4.5, 0>,  <91200256, 6048225, 6048233, CDMA_PP, 300, 28-02-2014 12:17:08, 5.5, 0>]
]]
```

those are return as String.so how to convert them as like below

element 1 = [1],
element 2 = [<2254, 89014103211118510720, C, D>], etc..

**EDIT** Dear  **abmitchell**

because they insert to sqlite like this after get those from arraylist

```
String dbQuery20 = result20.getProperty(0).toString();

                                        String[] statusarray3 = dbQuery20.split(",");
                                        String status20Value = statusarray3[0].toString();
                                        String status21Value = statusarray3[1].toString();
                                        String status22Value = statusarray3[2].toString();
                                        String editedValue3 = status20Value.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
                                        int status3 = Integer.parseInt(editedValue3);
                                        if (status3 == 1) {
                                            String userIdValue1 = statusarray3[1].toString();
                                            dbh.SaveLoginData(userIdValue1.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\<", ""),
                                                    statusarray3[3].toString(),
                                                    statusarray3[4].toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\>",""),
                                                    statusarray3[2].toString());
                                            dbh.SetLoginDetailsUpdatedDate(date);
                                        }
                                    }
```

thanks all now its ok with below code

```
s=s.replaceAll("\\[\\[","").replaceAll("]]","");
        List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(s.split(",")); 
        ArrayList listFinal=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arrayList));  
        System.out.println(listFinal);
```

Comment: You'll want to use something like Gson, which is a JSON parser. That's what it looks like the axis2 webservice is sending you. You can then easily create an Array from the JSON String. Or, you could build your own custom parser for this service if you know how it formats its responses

Comment: yes dear friend abmitchell. but here i have to involve with already done part of the application.so they did these as like this.if i'm going to add gson have to seperately change more phases of code.thatswhy i'm ask to String to arraylist method.
[i did gson part already in my application in my own task :-) ]

Comment: The output of the axis2 webservice isn't valid JSON.

Comment: yes dear Nathan.we get is as a string out put.
now those parts are ok and need to String to Arraylist part :-)

Comment: I'd suggest implementing your own method that will take a String and return the properly formatted ArrayList. Within that method, you will have to do something like the code you posted in your edit, but there's not going to be a way in Java to convert a formatted String into an ArrayList other than using `split(String regex)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use their weapons:

```
    s=s.replaceAll("\\[\\[","").replaceAll("]]","");

    List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(s.split(","));
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `replaceAll("[","").replaceAll("]","");` or am I missing something?

Comment: dear Trompetas Rouketas solution added above with the help of user987339 and Gil :-)

Answer (score 1):

Without converting to JSON object, then fishing out each array, I would do something like this:

```
str = str.substring(2, str.length() - 2); // Get rid of the first and last [[ / ]]
String[] strArray = str.split(",");
```